# WebSockets support not working on DXP 7.1

Tags: websocket, weblogic, liferay-dxp

I'm trying to test if WebSockets based communication works or not on a WebLogic server. To do so, I've deployed the [websocket-echo-portlet](https://github.com/cgoncas/liferay-websocket-echo) on a Liferay DXP instance running on a WebLogic server, but it doesn't work. More specifically, when I press the buttom 'Connect' on the `websocket-echo-portlet` view, the following message is displayed in the 'debug-area-text' text area of the portlet:

```
ERROR: undefined - DISCONNECTED
```

When looking at the log file, there it appears the following message:

```
2023-10-25 14:40:02.721 WARN  [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][code_jsp:174] {code="404", msg="/o/echo", uri=/o/echo}
```

The weird thing happens when I stop-start the OSGi module `com.liferay.websocket.whiteboard` on a Gogo console (once set the debug level value to 'TRACE' for the Logger `com.liferay.websocket` through the Control Panel of the Liferay instance), and then I look at the log file. There it appears the following message:

```
INFO  [Thread-56][BundleStartStopLogger:38] STOPPED com.liferay.websocket.whiteboard_2.0.0 [710]
INFO  [Thread-56][WebSocketEndpointTracker:59] A WebSocket server container is not registered
INFO  [Thread-56][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.websocket.whiteboard_2.0.0 [710]
```

That message is thrown by the `com.liferay.websocket.whiteboard.internal.WebSocketEndpointTracker` class (see it on [GitHub](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/f63d698232b7b620536bb32f854286b132fcc07a/modules/apps/websocket/websocket-whiteboard/src/main/java/com/liferay/websocket/whiteboard/internal/WebSocketEndpointTracker.java#L50)), when the `serverContainer` variable is `null`, that is, when the sentence `_servletContext.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer")` returns `null`, that is, when the `_servletContext` object doesn't have the attribute `"javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer"`. And the question is why that attribute hasn't been set into the `_servletContext` object? That object has been declared this way:

```
@Reference(target = "(original.bean=true)")
private ServletContext _servletContext;
```

It seems as if, either (1) on a WebLogic server, or (2) on the OSGi's module framework it was required to set any additional setting so that the `com.liferay.websocket.whiteboard` module works as expected.

Any clarification will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Background:

Liferay DXP 7.1.10-ga1, WebLogic 12.2.1.4, openjdk-1.8.0.232-1, Windows 10.

(It all is sort of a [cross-post](https://liferay.dev/en/ask/questions/development/com-liferay-websocket-whiteboard-module-not-working) issue)